# SSH Agent forward specific keys rather than all registered ssh keys

Tags: linux, github, amazon-web-services, ssh, ssh-keys

I am using agent forwarding, it works fine. But the ssh client is sharing all registered (ssh-add) keys with the remote server. I have personal keys that I don't want to share with the remote server. Is there a way to restrict with keys are being forwarded?

I have multiple github accounts and aws accounts. I don't want to share all the ssh-keys.

Comment: How did you end up solving this?

Comment: @AllenLuce  take a look at my answer below

Comment: @AllenLuce I use github/bitbucket repos for deploy on remote server. I use SSH keys for auth on github/bitbucket. I want that access to these repositories to be available only when I am logged in on the server. That's what I need to forward SSH key for. But I do not want ALL my personal/work keys to be available on server that I want to deploy repo to. Only the keys explicitly required for deploy should be forwarded.

Comment: @AllenLuce if remote server got hacked, I do not want anybody to access my repos, that's why I do not store keys on server. And if remote server got hacked, and hacker knows I use agent forwarding, I do not want allow him to use my forwarded agent for anything other than authenticating to these repos in the worst case.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like it is possible with OpenSSH 6.7 - it supports unix socket forwarding. We could start secondary ssh-agent with specific keys and forward it's socket to remote host. Unfortunately this version is not available for my server/client systems at the time of writing.

I have found another possible solution, using [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/) and standard SSH TCP forwarding.

### Idea

1. On local host we run secondary ssh-agent with only keys we want to see on remote host.
2. On local host we set up forwarding of TCP connections on some port (portXXX) to secondary ssh-agent's socket.
3. On remote host we set up forwarding from some socket to some TCP port (portYYY).
4. Then we establish ssh connection with port forwarding from remote's portYYY to local portXXX.

Requests to ssh agent go like this:

```
local ssh-agent (secondary)
    ^
    |
    v
/tmp/ssh-.../agent.ZZZZZ   - agent's socket
    ^
    |   (socat local)
    v
localhost:portXXX
    ^
    |   (ssh port forwarding)
    v
 remote's localhost:portYYY
    ^
    |   (socat remote)
    v
 $HOME/tmp/agent.socket
    ^
    |   (requests for auth via agent)
    v
 SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$HOME/tmp/agent.socket
    ^
    |   (uses SSH_AUTH_SOCK variable to find agent socket)
    v
   ssh
```

### Drawbacks

1. It is not completely secure, because ssh-agent becomes partially available through TCP: users of remote host can connect to your local agent on 127.0.0.1:portYYY, and other users of your local host can connect on 127.0.0.1:portXXX. But they will see only limited set of keys you manually added to this agent. And, as [AllenLuce mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30656166/1775065), they can't grab it, they only could use it for authentication while agent is running.
2. `socat` must be installed on remote host. But looks like it is possible to simply upload precompiled binary (I tested it on FreeBSD and it works).
3. No automation: keys must be added manually via `ssh-add`, forwarding requires 2 extra processes (socat) to be run, multiple ssh connections must be managed manually.

So, this answer is probably just a proof of concept and not a production solution.

Let's see how it can be done.

### Instruction

#### Client side (where ssh-agent is running)

Run new ssh-agent. It will be used for keys you want to see on remote host only.

```
$ ssh-agent # below is ssh-agent output, DO NOT ACTUALLY RUN THESE COMMANDS BELOW
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-qVnT0UsgV6yO/agent.22982; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=22983; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
```

It prints some variables. Do not set them: you will loose your main ssh agent. Set another variable with suggested value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`:

```
SSH_AUTH_SECONDARY_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-qVnT0UsgV6yO/agent.22982
```

Then establish forwarding from some TCP port to our ssh-agent socket locally:

```
PORT=9898
socat TCP4-LISTEN:$PORT,bind=127.0.0.1,fork UNIX-CONNECT:$SSH_AUTH_SECONDARY_SOCK &
```

`socat` will run in background. Do not forget to `kill` it when you're done.

Add some keys using `ssh-add`, but run it with modified enviromnent variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SECONDARY_SOCK ssh-add
```

#### Server side (remote host)

Connect to remote host with port forwarding. Your **main** (not secondary)  ssh agent will be used for auth on hostA (but will not be available from it, as we do not forward it).

```
home-host$ PORT=9898 # same port as above
home-host$ ssh -R $PORT:localhost:$PORT userA@hostA
```

On remote host establish forwarding from ssh-agent socket to same TCP port as on your home host:

```
remote-host$ PORT=9898 # same port as on home host
remote-host$ mkdir -p $HOME/tmp
remote-host$ SOCKET=$HOME/tmp/ssh-agent.socket
remote-host$ socat UNIX-LISTEN:$SOCKET,fork TCP4:localhost:$PORT &
```

`socat` will run in background. Do not forget to `kill` it when you're done. It does not automatically exit when you close ssh connection.

#### Connection

On remote host set enviromnent variable for ssh to know where agent socket (from previous step) is. It can be done in same ssh session or in parallel one.

```
remote-host$ export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$HOME/tmp/ssh-agent.socket
```

Now it is possible to use secondary agent's keys on remote host:

```
remote-host$ ssh userB@hostB # uses secondary ssh agent
Welcome to hostB!
```

Answer (score 4):

The keys themselves are not shared by forwarding your agent.  What's forwarded is the ability to contact the ssh-agent on your local host.  Remote systems send challenge requests through the forwarding tunnel. They do not request the keys themselves.

See http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html#fwd for a graphical explanation.